# Does Windows 10 slows Acer Aspire E5-411-C3K3 notebooks?

Tags: windows-8.1, acer-aspire

So I have an Acer Aspire E5 notebook and I recently reformatted it. I installed Windows 8.1 (in Legacy Boot -- I actually don't know what difference it makes) and I want to update to Windows 10. I just wanna inquire if Windows 10 would slow my laptop down. AND, what difference does the Legacy boot make if I update it.

Comment: Windows 10 is faster or as fast as Windows 8.1.  Legacy boot means your using a MBR partition drive instead of the fast GPT UEFI boot

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, machines that ran Windows 8.1 should be able to run Windows 10 without issues.

In the small chance that you feel it isnt working as you would like, Windows will allow you to rollback to the Windows 8.1.  You have 30 days to make that decision, which is more than enough time.

You do not need `legacy boot mode` if you are upgrading from within the OS.